# Trying to install SyliusProductBundle on Symfony 5.4: LocaleNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony, locale, symfony5, sylius

I am trying to install the standalone `SyliusProductBundle` on Symfony 5.4, but keep getting a `LocaleNotFoundException`: `"Locale could not be found!"`

Started with a clean Symfony 5.4 installation (`--webapp`) then followed the (outdated) documentation here: https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.12/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusProductBundle/installation.html

Installed the bundle:

```
composer require sylius/product-bundle -w
```

Added the bottom 3 lines to `bundles.php` manually because they weren't added automatically:

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    winzou\Bundle\StateMachineBundle\winzouStateMachineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Bazinga\Bundle\HateoasBundle\BazingaHateoasBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    BabDev\PagerfantaBundle\BabDevPagerfantaBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\SyliusResourceBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle::class => ['all' => true],

    Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\SyliusProductBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sylius\Bundle\AttributeBundle\SyliusAttributeBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sylius\Bundle\LocaleBundle\SyliusLocaleBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

Created `config/config.yml`:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            sluggable: true
            timestampable: true
```

And updated the database:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Now when I try to get a product repository it throws the `LocaleNotFoundException`:

```
$repository = $this->container->get('sylius.repository.product');
```

I've tried adding the locale manually in the `sylius_locale` table, as described here, but that doesn't seem to work: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/8976#issuecomment-468678369

Also tried renaming the `sylius_locale` table to `sylius_channel_locales` (as per the last comment in that issue) and adding the locale to that, but that doesn't work either.

How can I set the locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the issues here:
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/8452
and
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/7853

The solution is to replace the `Kernel.php` file in the `src` directory with the following:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition("sylius.context.locale.composite");
        $definition->setDecoratedService(null);
    }
}
```

You do not have to add the locale to the database.